# Function of functionals?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, differential-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Could you please let me know if there is a branch studying the functions of functionals?

After spending hours of researching and reading I found nothing. I must be on the wrong track.

As a math newbie and lover, I appreciate your help.

Comment: There's duality, and the double dual is a space of functionals of functionals. There's lots of things about 'operators' in general. Things like variational calculus, differential equations, etc.

Comment: The functionals on the tangent bundle to a manifold constitute the *cotangent bundle* on that manifold.  Thus, you would be looking at functions on the cotangent bundle.  The general context for this is differential geometry.  For basics, check out V. Arnol'd's "Mathematical methods of classical mechanics" and "Lectures on Partial Differential Equations".

Comment: For infinite-dimensional spaces, duality, as mentioned in a comment above.  You'd be looking at the weak-* topology; start with Kolmogorov and Fomin's book.